# Is there an advantage of using multisite if I have multiple WordPress websites for myself?

Tags: multisite

I have multiple WordPress websites, they all have their own domain and are standalone. Is there an advantage of using multisite? Or is my current setup good?

Answer (score 4):

I'll just put the main pros/cons that quickly came to my mind here. This list is *not* extensive. For some more info on MS have a look at at the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network).

## Pro Multisite

- Maintain WordPress/Plugins/Themes just once. If you upgrade everything is upgraded at once
- Easily share content between sites. (e.g [switch to blog](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/switch_to_blog))
- User Accounts can be cross-site
- Sites are totally independent

## Contra Multisite

- You can't update WordPress/Plugins/Themes separately
- Some plugins do not work properly on MS
- Adds some complexity on top of everything
- When something breaks it *might* break everything all at once